# XML validation using python

Tags: python, xml

I am looking a python code which returns "XML is good" when each starting tag has corresponding matching ending tag in XML file and all <, >, / are present correctly. If starting tag has no corresponding matchin ending tag or if any of <, >, / is missing then code should return "XML is not good". I am new to xml, python. Thanks in advance.

Sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Use an XML parsing library, for example [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

Comment: This is called wellformedness checking, not validation. Validation in XML means checking that the contents of each element match the content permitted by a DTD or schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas commented, you can parse the sample XML file with ElementTree, if you got `ParseError` then you would catch it by printing the message:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
try:
    tree = ET.parse('s.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    print("XML is good")
except ParseError:
    print("XML is not good")
```